C++ initialization of a thread in a constructor
Given this code in C++:

#include <vector>
#include <thread>

class MyClass {
    std::thread workerThread;
    std::vector<int> vec;
public:
     MyClass(): 
     workerThread(&MyClass::myLoop, this),
      vec(){}

}

void MyClass::myLoop() {
   int x= 0;
   for (size_t i=0; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
      x = vec[i];
   }
} 

Is it possible that when creating instance of type MyClass the worker thread will that is created in the constructor will start executing the myLoop function before vec is initialized resulting in undefined behavior?

yep, declare your members in the order you want them initialised

Yes, Member variables are initialized in declaration order.

This is not undefined behavior, it is expected behavior. You really should declare vec as first member. In fact this rule gives you a lot of control over the lifetime over variables/objects so use this knowledge to your advantage.
